# Get the API Definition for a Function App published from Visual Studio as a zip

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions

I have implemented an Azure Function App in Visual Studio and deployed the package with the recomended 'Zip Deploy'. This means the Function App is in read-only mode on the azure portal  and when trying to create a API defintion i get the Message:

API definition (Swagger) is not available for Function Apps in readonly mode.

In the function app settings the toggle to "Read/Write" at the Function app edit mode is greyed out too.

How can i get an API definition?
I want to use it to connect the function with PowerApps or Flow.

Comment: I don't know the answer but maybe this link has some info? It sounds like the .yaml file for the open api spec needs to be in the zip you deploy, somehow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-api-definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenAPI preview feature is **only available today in the 1.x runtime**. For v1, you could create an OpenAPI definitionFunction like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition). For v2, API definition feature is **not support for beta runtime currently**. Here is a document about [OpenAPI 2.0 metadata support in Azure Functions (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-api-definition).

Workaround:

Use an external library [Aliencube.AzureFunctions.Extensions.OpenApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aliencube.AzureFunctions.Extensions.OpenApi/) which uses the HTTP triggers on Azure Functions, you can use this on **both version 1.x and 2.x**.

For more details about how to Rendering Open API Document you could refer to this [article](https://devkimchi.com/2019/02/02/introducing-swagger-ui-on-azure-functions/).

Comment: thanks...helpful links.
Even when I expected more a 'azure portal inside' solution i mark this answer